# Capture image in android device using keyevent

Tags: selenium, appium

I am trying to use the below code to capture the image and save it but while running the code , this part is ignored

`((AndroidDriver<?>) getDriver()).pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.KEYCODE_CAMERA);`

Is there any alternate way to tap on the "click" button of the camera.

Comment: are you trying to take screenshots?

Comment: @Gaurav no i don't think so, the intent is to capture image using camera here

Comment: @Vignesh what java-client version are you using?

Comment: Previously `driver.sendKeyevent(27);` used to do the trick. See if that works for you.

Comment: This code is not working in my case while KEYCODE_BACK is working. Can you share your code? What else you have done to launch camera and click ok button.

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code snippet**

```
((AndroidDriver<?>) driver).pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.CAMERA));
```

For your reference list of [AndroidKeys](https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/android/nativekey/AndroidKey.html)